# Eclipse - pointer to function parameters hints

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Showing parameters hint of a function is very practical thing and good way to save time.
Is there a way how Eclipse display parameters hits for a pointer to function.

```
struct {
    void (*bar)(p1, p2, p3...);
} foo;
foo.bar("Ctrl+Space")
```

report the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.index.composite.c.CompositeCField cannot be cast to [Lorg.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.IBinding;
```

Comment: You have found a bug! Is it reproducible all the time? Can you report it please: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT

Comment: I submitted it, please add yourself to CC list to keep up with progress on fix: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517954

Comment: Yes It is reproducible all time. I have send a report like 6 months ago. When I google error report it send me on an issue with resolved status https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405168 , why I have asked the question.

Comment: I'm using LPCXpresso a based-Eclipse IDE (CDT-v 8.8.1.201602051005). I mean once a bug is fixed can I fix it by my own on my IDE, or have to report it to LPC?. The bug also present on eclipse neon3 (CDT-v 9.2)

Comment: @Abderrezak [Bug 405168](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405168) concerned a different bug with a similar error message.

Comment: @Abderrezak: You would probably need to wait until LPC releases a new version of their IDE, based on CDT 9.3 or higher. Manually installing a newer CDT version into an LPC installation *may* work or it may not; it's best to ask LPC about that.

Comment: They stop supporting LPCXpresso. Well, I will wait for the CDT-9.3 and I'll try to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ClassCastException is being fixed in [bug 517954](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517954) which Jonah kindly filed.

However, the ClassCastException is not the reason for having no parameter hints. Showing parameter hints based on a function pointer's type is just something that hasn't been implemented in CDT. [Bug 517978](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517978) is now on file for that.